# How to merge two DataTable with sum in C#

Tags: c#, datatable, merge

I have two table.

I need to merge them into a table, with composite rows of number columns where the item_id is the same.

The number of rows in the table is large, so the fastest processing solution is well judged here.

Table 1:

```
item_id|item_name|qty|col1|col2|col3|
===============================================
1      |apple    |5  |xxx |xxx |xxx |
2      |orange   |10 |xxx |xxx |xxx |
3      |tomato   |7  |xxx |xxx |xxx |
```

Table 2:

```
item_id|item_name|qty|col1|col2|col3|
===============================================
1      |apple    |5  |xxx |xxx |xxx |
3      |tomato   |5  |xxx |xxx |xxx |
4      |squash   |1  |xxx |xxx |xxx |
```

===> Table result:

```
item_id|item_name|qty|col1|col2|col3|
===============================================
1      |apple    |10 |xxx |xxx |xxx | (sum qty: 10)
2      |orange   |10 |xxx |xxx |xxx |
3      |tomato   |12 |xxx |xxx |xxx | (sum qty: 12)
4      |squash   |1  |xxx |xxx |xxx |
```

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? Show some code!

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: Why are you using a DataTable in the first place? Why aren't you using strongly typed objects?

Comment: Thank. I'm looking for a solution to the problem, not a specific source code. If someone can provide the example code then too good.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward solution would be using `UNION` and then `GROUP BY` on `item_id` using `SUM` function on `qty` field, like:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM Table2
```

and so on.

in C# the `DataTable` merge operation could be implemented as follows:

```
table3 = Table1.Copy();
table3.Merge(Table2);
```

then you can loop through the result `table3` or use `LINQ`.

(note: your question is a kind of generic so the answer is also generic-like).

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank Alex Bell, but here are 2 DataTable in C #, not in SQL, how to use UNION with this case.

Comment: You are welcome. Please refer to my extended answer. Rgds,

Comment: @XuanDung - From your comment above: `I'm looking for a solution to the problem, not a specific source code`. The above is good enough.

Comment: @Igor Thanks a bunch Igor. My best,

Comment: You are welcome Xuan! Good luck with your project, it's not that difficult and the aforementioned technique will do the job. Rgds,

Answer (score 0):

I never used C# `datatable` but a simple loop could do what you want.

```
foreach(row1 in datatable1.Rows)
{
    foreach(row2 in datatable2.Rows)
    {

        if (!datatable3.Rows.Contains(row1))
            datatable3.Rows.Add(row1)

        if (!datatable3.Rows.Contains(row1))
            datatable3.Rows.Add(row1)

        if (row1.id == row2.id)
            datatable3.row.qty = row1.qty + row2.qty
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the two DataTable's in a var or list, then you can do a group by: something like this.

```
 var listadoTabla1 = new List<Table1>
        {
            new Table1{ item_id=1, item_name="apple", qty=5 },
            new Table1{ item_id=2, item_name="orange", qty=10 },
            new Table1{ item_id=3, item_name="tomato", qty=7 }

        };
        var listadoTabla2 = new List<Table1>
        {
            new Table1{ item_id=1, item_name="apple", qty=5 },
            new Table1{ item_id=3, item_name="tomato", qty=1 },
            new Table1{ item_id=4, item_name="squash", qty=5 }
        };


        var listadoResultado = listadoTabla1;
        listadoResultado.AddRange(listadoTabla2);

        var resultado = (from x in listadoResultado
                         group x by new { x.item_id, x.item_name }
                                         into grp
                         select new Table1
                         {
                             item_id = grp.Key.item_id,
                             item_name = grp.Key.item_name,
                             qty = grp.Sum(x=>x.qty)

                         }).ToList();
```

See ya!